# Ctrl+Alt+F[1-12] don't switch to TTY

Tags: tty

After I installed my new keyboard, I discovered that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> (where n is a number 1-12) keys no longer brings me to the tty screens (nothing happens), but `sudo chvt 1` in the terminal emulator can start the tty. Meanwhile, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> could bring me back to the x-window.

My keyboard is [i-rocks IK6](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=i-rocks%20IK6&ia=images&iax=images) (I didn't have such problem when using my old Logitech K120 keyboard)

How should I fix this problem? My system is Ubuntu 14.04 with Kernel 3.19.0-27-generic

Comment: please try `sudo service tty1 restart` and then try to login to tty using Ctrl+Alt+F1....any change??

Comment: Does your keyboard have a Fn combination key? This can be an issue if the OS autoenables the Fn key, in which you have to press it to disable it (ie, Ctrl + Alt + Fn + F1 might work).

Comment: The kbd has a [Windows and application keys disabled function](http://www.i-rocks.com/products/crystal-usb-keyboard). It is turned on and off using `[Fn][F11]`.

Comment: @userunknown Done.

Answer (score 0):

The i-rocks IK6 Crystal USB Keyboard has, what they call, a [Windows and application keys disabled function](http://www.i-rocks.com/products/crystal-usb-keyboard).

The function is turned on and off using <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

There is even a small Windows icon on the <kbd>F11</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem in my Dell Precision 5510 after a login loop that seems to happen due to a recent update of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I finally found that the ESC key has a small Fn icon attached so I combined this with the Fn key and the blockade was released. Ctrl+Alt+F1 worked now and I could log in from the console.ç

çI have to fix now the issue of the login loop... I'll try with the suggestions I already found here.